# SQL select, pad with chronological missing months

Tags: sql, sql-server

Notice the `2015-02` and `2015-03` months are missing in the output from the following group by `SQL`. If there is no data for a month I want to show the month and `0`. Anyone know how to go about this?

```
SELECT convert(char(7), MeterReadDate, 121),count(*)
FROM [myTable]
where (MeterReadDate > dateadd(d,-356,getdate()))
group by  convert(char(7), MeterReadDate, 121)
order by  convert(char(7), MeterReadDate, 121)
```

Sample data:

```
YYYY-MM COUNT
2014-06 23
2014-07 42
2014-08 80
2014-09 92
2014-10 232
2014-11 88
2014-12 8
2015-01 5
2015-04 2
2015-05 1
```

Still cannot clear the missing rows, here is where I am with it..

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = dateadd(m,-12,getdate()), @EndDate DATETIME = getdate(), @DATE DATETIME

DECLARE @TEMP AS TABLE (MeterReadDate datetime)

SET @DATE = @StartDate

WHILE @DATE <= @EndDate
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES ( @DATE)
    SET @DATE = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@DATE)
END



SELECT convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121),count(*)

  FROM @TEMP m left join
     [myTable] t
     on convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121) = convert(char(7), m.MeterReadDate, 121)

  where (t.MeterReadDate > dateadd(m,-12,getdate()))
  group by  convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121)
  order by  convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121)
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` from a calendar table

Comment: Daniel E.  your comment is an answer.  Maybe you can flesh it out just a bit and post it as an answer.

Comment: Oh well, beat me to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to go beyond your `min` and `max` dates of your results then you can do the following:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT convert(char(7), MeterReadDate, 121) AS [Date], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
               FROM [myTable]
               WHERE (MeterReadDate > dateadd(d,-356,getdate()))
               GROUP by  convert(char(7), MeterReadDate, 121)
             ),
        minmax
          AS ( SELECT   CAST(MIN([Date] + '-01') AS DATE) AS mind ,
                        CAST(MAX([Date] + '-01') AS DATE) maxd
               FROM     cte
             ),
        calendar
          AS ( SELECT   mind ,
                        CONVERT(CHAR(7), mind, 121) AS cmind
               FROM     minmax
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(mm, 1, calendar.mind) ,
                        CONVERT(CHAR(7), DATEADD(mm, 1, calendar.mind), 121)
               FROM     calendar
                        CROSS JOIN minmax
               WHERE    calendar.mind < minmax.maxd
             )
    SELECT  c.cmind AS [Date],
            ISNULL(cte.[Count], 0) AS [Count]
    FROM    calendar c
            LEFT JOIN cte ON c.cmind = cte.[Date]
    OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

Comment: This worked first time, all the other attempts were still missing the rows, THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need a list of dates/months that covers the entire period.  Here is one method using a recursive CTE:

```
with months as (
      select cast(getdate() - 365) as thedate
      union all
      select date_add(1, month, thedate)
      from months
      where thedate <= getdate()
     )
select convert(char(7), m.thedate, 121) as yyyy-mm, count(t.MeterReadDate)
from months m left join
     [myTable] t
     on convert(char(7), MeterReadDate, 121) = convert(char(7), m.thedate, 121)
group by convert(char(7), m.thedate, 121)
order by convert(char(7), m.thedate, 121);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to join onto a table containing calendar information, one way to do this without actually altering the database schema (and is more dynamic in my opinion) would be to use a table variable and the `DATEADD()` function.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2015-01-01', @EndDate DATETIME = '2015-12-01', @DATE DATETIME

DECLARE @TEMP AS TABLE ([DATE] DATETIME)

SET @DATE = @StartDate

WHILE @DATE <= @EndDate
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES (@DATE)
    SET @DATE = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@DATE)
END


SELECT * FROM @TEMP
```

Set `@Start` and `@End` to your required dates, then just join onto your results set!

**UPDATE:**

To extract the date in the format you gave above under "sample data", meaning you would be able to join onto the table, use:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(YEAR([DATE]),'-',right('0' + cast(month([DATE]) as varchar),2)) 
FROM @TEMP
LEFT JOIN MyTable ON...
```

Comment: gr8 answer, i'm just not sure best way to join to @temp now, any ideas?

Comment: its the join I cannot figure, I think it needs to be a union perhaps

Comment: Cannot you not join the two dates together if they are in the same format? Union may be easier, without posting more code I cannot see what it wrong.

Comment: thanks, i'm so close, had to post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485276/create-missing-months-dynamically-from-group-on-date-field it was getting messy