# Create missing months dynamically from group on date field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

In the following SQL i'm trying to insert rows to fill in the missing months in the results. The solution is very close thanks to post [SQL select, pad with chronological missing months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480383/sql-select-pad-with-chronological-missing-months)

But yet this code runs gr8 but still have missing months, issue is how to join/union the temp table

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = dateadd(m,-12,getdate()), @EndDate DATETIME = getdate(), @DATE DATETIME

DECLARE @TEMP AS TABLE (MeterReadDate datetime)

SET @DATE = @StartDate

WHILE @DATE <= @EndDate
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES ( @DATE)
    SET @DATE = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@DATE)
END



SELECT convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121),count(*)

  FROM @TEMP m left join
     [PremiseMeterReadProviders] t
     on convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121) = convert(char(7), m.MeterReadDate, 121)

  where (t.MeterReadDate > dateadd(m,-12,getdate()))
  group by  convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121)
  order by  convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: I think a join is no good, maybe needs to be a union to add missing rows from temp table

Comment: ANSWERED here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480383/sql-select-pad-with-chronological-missing-months

Comment: Solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480383/sql-select-pad-with-chronological-missing-months

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
;WITH Months AS 
(
 SELECT TOP 12 
   CONVERT(CHAR(7),
       DATEADD(MONTH 
               , - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
               , GETDATE()
               )
           ,121) MonthNo
 FROM master..spt_values
 )
SELECT convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121),count(*)
FROM Months m
LEFT JOIN  [PremiseMeterReadProviders] t
      ON convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121) = m.MonthNo
     AND (t.MeterReadDate > dateadd(m,-12,getdate()))
group by  convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121)
order by  convert(char(7), t.MeterReadDate, 121)
```

Comment: that runs ge8 but still missing FEB and MAR 2015

Comment: This code is super neat and no need for temp tables, but its returning 1st row as NULL and 3, then 2014-06 and 25 and so on then it still skips from Jan to April in 2015 (back to initial problem). Feel its really close tho

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reconstruct the query as below

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = dateadd(m,-12,getdate()), @EndDate DATETIME = getdate(), @DATE DATETIME

DECLARE @TEMP AS TABLE (MeterReadDate datetime)

SET @DATE = @StartDate

WHILE @DATE <= @EndDate
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES ( @DATE)
    SET @DATE = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@DATE)
END



SELECT convert(char(7), m.MeterReadDate, 121),count(*)

  FROM @TEMP m left join
     [Announcement] t
     on convert(char(7), t.ExpiryDate, 121) = convert(char(7), m.MeterReadDate, 121)

  WHERE (t.ExpiryDate IS NULL OR t.ExpiryDate > dateadd(m,-12,getdate()))
  group by  convert(char(7), m.MeterReadDate, 121)
  order by  convert(char(7), m.MeterReadDate, 121)
```

In the where condition, I added t.ExpiryDate IS NULL, because this will be null for the missing month.