# create a view to insert missing month and copy data from previous row to that missing month

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a view, which will insert Missing Month and copy data from the previous month to missing month.
 For example I have below three columns as you can see month 4 and 7 are missing, so in month 4 month 3 data will be copied and in month 7 month 6 data will be copied
and I want to specify min and max dates

```
CID-----PID-----Time  
2222-----7------06-03-2015  
2222-----7------08-05-2015  
2222-----7------29-05-2015  
2222-----8------01-06-2015  
2222-----8------01-06-2015  
2222-----8------11-08-2015  
2222-----8------11-08-2015  
2222-----8------20-08-2015 
3539     5      17-04-2015
3539     8      12-08-2015
4987     10     06-03-2015
4987     12     01-06-2015
4987     13     17-07-2015
```

I want output like this in View

```
CID---- PID---Time  
2222--- 7-----201503  
2222--- 7-----201504  
2222----7-----201505  
2222----8-----201506  
2222----8-----201507  
2222----8-----201508 
3539    5     201504
3539    5     201505
3539    5     201506
3539    5     201507
3539    8     201508
4987    10    201503
4987    10    201504
4987    10    201505
4987    12    201506
4987    13    201507
4987    13    201508
```

There is similar question/Answer posted but I’m unable to apply to my case.
[SQL select, pad with chronological missing months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480383/sql-select-pad-with-chronological-missing-months)

Comment: Is `CID` and `PID` always the same in one months?

Comment: Hi Werndried, Thanks, Yes CID will remain same but PID will change, suppose If I change something in CID in month 8 Then PID will become 9, but I don't think we need to worry about PID, because we just only want to copy previous month data to missing month.

Comment: Still not clear. Why does PID=5 goes up to 201507 and not 201508? What is the upper time for each record?

Comment: Upper Time Will be last month, We are in month 9, so everything goes till month 8, once we are month 10, results will be till month 9, if there was no changes in month 8, previous record will be copied to month 9, if I can get till current month, it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this one:

```
WITH 
m AS
    (SELECT ADD_MONTHS((SELECT MIN(TRUNC(MON_TIME, 'MM')) FROM My_Table), LEVEL-1) AS all_months 
    FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS((SELECT MIN(TRUNC(MON_TIME, 'MM')) FROM My_Table), LEVEL-1) <= (SELECT MAX(MON_TIME) FROM My_Table))
SELECT DISTINCT 
    NVL(CID, LEAD(CID, 1) OVER (ORDER BY all_months)) AS CID,
    NVL(PID, LEAD(PID, 1) OVER (partition by CID ORDER BY all_months)) AS PID,
    TO_CHAR(all_months, 'YYYYMM') AS TIME   
FROM m
     LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Table ON TRUNC(MON_TIME, 'MM') = all_months
ORDER BY 3;

CID PID TIME
2222    7   201503
2222    7   201504
2222    7   201505
2222    8   201506
2222    8   201507
2222    8   201508
```

Comment: Hi wernfried, I'm extremely sorry, now I understand why you were asking about cid, yes cid is cliend Id and there are many client in the database

Comment: I updated my answer but I still have no idea what you try to achieve. You sample data is too low.

Comment: Hi wernfried, thanks for your time and sorry for not being clear, I have added some more data, please let me know if still require any clarification, as I said, the code I posted doing what I need, you can add any number of data and test that code it will add Zero for missing month for that particular CID, but instead of that I need last know value, let's just say copy everything from previous row to missing month, the solution you have posted will not work as there are thousand of different CID in database.

Comment: This is just to show some sample data, you have to replace it with your real data

Comment: Do you understand now?

Comment: sorry wernfried, but still not getting right result, have you tested it, it's not adding missing month, I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi wernfried, sorry for late reply, thanks for your time and effort.